# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: personname: , while compiling: SELECT id, personname FROM numbersTable

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sqlite

im a new in android,I want get data in db to textview.

but it has error I cannot correct this problem.

Please help me.

This is DB class

```
    public class blockornot1 {
     String TAG;
 private dbHelper1 ourHelper;
 private final Context ourContext;
 private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabese;

  public final static  String DATABASE_NAME1="databasename.db";
  public final String DATABASE_TABLE="numbersTable";
  public final String KEY_NAME="personname";
  public final String KEY_ID="id";
  public final int DATABASE_VERSION =2;


  public  class dbHelper1 extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public dbHelper1 (Context context) {
          super (context,DATABASE_NAME1,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
          }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+ DATABASE_TABLE+ "("+KEY_ID+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "               
      + KEY_NAME + "TEXT NOT NULL);");
        Log.v(TAG, "creat");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);

    }

  }``

  public blockornot1(Context c){

      ourContext = c;
  }

  public blockornot1 open() throws SQLException{
      ourHelper= new dbHelper1(ourContext);
      ourDatabese= ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
      return this;
  }

  public void close(){
      ourHelper.close();

  }

public long creatEntry(String inputtext) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv= new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_NAME, inputtext);
    Log.v(inputtext, "add to database");
    return ourDatabese.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

}

public String getData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ID, KEY_NAME };
    Cursor c=ourDatabese.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null,   null);
    String result = "";
    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID);
    int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
    for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){

        result= result + c.getString(iRow) + "   " + c.getString(iName) + "/n";
    }
    return result;
   }


     }
```

and this is my main class

```
      public class Mainclass extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
      EditText et;
  String TAG;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.v(TAG,"onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

       et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
       Button bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button bt1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2view);
        bt.setOnClickListener(this);
        bt1.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

        public void onClick(View v) {

            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                boolean dididwork =true;
                try{
                 String inputtext=et.getText().toString();
                 blockornot1 entry= new blockornot1(Mainclass.this);
                 entry.open();
                 entry.creatEntry(inputtext);
                 entry.close();
                 Log.v(TAG," okkkkkkk hastaaaaaaa");
                break;}
                catch (Exception e){
                    String error=e.toString();
                    Dialog d= new Dialog(this);
                    d.setTitle("Heack ya!"); 
                            TextView t= new TextView(this);
                            t.setText(error);
                            d.setContentView(t);
                            d.show();
                    dididwork=false;

                }finally {
                if(dididwork){
                    Dialog d= new Dialog(this);
                    d.setTitle("Heack ya!"); 
                            TextView t= new   TextView(this);
                            t.setText("success");
                            d.setContentView(t);
                            d.show();

                }

                }

            case R.id.button2view:
                Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.SQLVIEW");  
                startActivity(i);
                break;

            }




                  }
```

}

and this class is for display DB in textview

```
   public class ShowDb extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sqlview);
    TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewsqlview);
    blockornot1 info= new blockornot1(this);
    info.open();
    String data= info.getData();
    info.close();
    tv.setText(data);
}
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing that you changed the table's create statement at some point, but until you increment the database version your app will not automatically implement any changes. Try setting the `DATABASE_VERSION` to `3`.

**Addition**

If you are going to bind the information in your database to a ListView, Spinner, etc then you should change `KEY_ID` to `_id`. (Android is particular about the name of the primary key column.)

Comment: To carify for the OP, when the old database version doesnt match the new database version the `onUpgrade` method is fired, this is useful when you have database structure changes.  You can write code that transfers old data from old style database to your new versions.  Since yours just drops and calls onCreate this will ensure the database has the latest structure.

Comment: thanks you for useful information,i did as you said but still have problem ,new error:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist

Comment: You have two options: 1) Change `KEY_ID` to `"_id"` (not `"id"`) and rebuild your database by setting `DATABASE_VERSION = 4`. **Or** 2) Add `"as _id"` to this line: `String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ID as _id, KEY_NAME };`.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1) Change `KEY_ID` to `_id` (not `id`) and rebuild your database by setting `DATABASE_VERSION = 4`.

Or

2) Add `as _id` to this line: `String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ID as _id, KEY_NAME };`.

I had the same problem at the moment to show the information in my database to a ListView, so I followed this instructions  given by 'Sam', that really solved my problem. Thanks so much Sam.